# SQL syntax error - Why?

Tags: php, sql, syntax

I've looked over this code a zillion times and can't see anything wrong with it.  But it gives me the message, "Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'when, name, reporter, contacts, suggestions, remarks) VALUES ('Me again', 'me', ' at line 1"

HELP PLEASE!

Sorry, sorry, I'm so Sooooooory!  Was in a hurry to get to a job, and I pasted the wrong code.  Here is the correct line of code.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO one_on_one_reports (whenever, name, reporter, contacts, suggestions, remarks) VALUES ('$_POST[whenever]', '$_POST[name]', '$_POST[reporter]', '$_POST[contacts]', '$_POST[suggestions]', '$_POST[remarks]')";
```

I'm in between driving runs.  And gotta run again.  But again my apologies for the wrong paste.  I'll consider the protection against injection later.  This file is in a password protected folder if that makes any difference.

Bruce

Comment: There is *definitely* something wrong with this code: **you're not sanitizing your query parameters!!** Consider this as a partial answer too.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The code you show is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). Use the proper sanitation method of your library (like `mysql_real_escape_string()` for the classic mysql library), or switch to PDO and prepared statements.

Comment: Are you sure that the error is associated with this particular query? I see fields in the error that are not in your query.

Comment: Can you post the full query, please?  I'm thinking you're not properly escaping your data and it's causing you issues.

Comment: Agree with all previous comments. The code you posted doesn't seem to be the correct bit. Where is `when, name, reporter, contacts, suggestions, remarks` in the insert list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like the error is not coming from the query you expect. The field names mentioned in the error are not listed:

```
when, name, reporter, contacts, suggestions, remarks
```

The error is quite simple, WHEN is a reserved keyword, you need to escape it.

```
`when`, name, reporter, contacts, suggestions, remarks
```

Speaking of escaping, you're not too strong on it, use the appropriate escape function on data to avoid SQL injections.

Answer (score 3):

`WHEN` is a [reserved word in mySQL.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

Either rename the column, or wrap it in backticks:

```
`WHEN`
```

Comment: This busted my balls when writing a web app that catalogued music Releases, turns out 'release' is also a reserved word :) Always good to be reminded!

Answer (score 2):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

**when** is a reserved word

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[name]);
$vote = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[vote]) ;
$comments = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[comments]) ;

$sql="INSERT INTO ms_poll (name, vote, comments) VALUES ('$name', '$vote', '$comments')";
```

Comment: It doesn't really address the issue, but +1 for showing how to escape database strings

Answer (score 0):

try putting curly braces around the POST parameters - after sanitizing them of course

like this

```
$sql="INSERT INTO ms_poll (name, vote, comments) VALUES ('{$_POST['name']}', '{$_POST['vote']}', '{$_POST['comments']}')";
```

To sanitize your incoming data i recommend using native methods NOT addslashes() ( if you are mysql then probably mysql_real_escape_string() or a better idea is to use the improved extensions which would mean using mysqli_real_escape_string() )

Comment: lol - i didnt spot the missing tables thing until looking at the post 4 mins ago - I too would start there!